# Downloading a file using curl or wget whose link is not given?

Tags: curl, wget

Here is the link of the file

```
https://rec.ustc.edu.cn/share/031c0580-0366-11ed-bb15-47281881a56b
```

it there is a zip file which can be downloaded when clicked on download option
one cant copy that link to download using wget or curl

I tried

```
wget https://rec.ustc.edu.cn/share/031c0580-0366-11ed-bb15-47281881a56b
```

and it wont download the file

is it doable in this case?
if so , how

Thanks

Comment: So... You basically want a command-line web browser with JavaScript support that's suitable for automation.

Comment: not really, I just want to download that file called pretrained_model.zip downloaded on my server @ÁlvaroGonzález

Comment: ... which is served by a client-side JavaScript application designed to run on top of a web browser.

Comment: You can peek the source code an see if there's an obvious reference to the real URL you can extract with simple text processors like `sed`. If it's dynamically generated, it won't be that easy.